# Whether urlencode is needed when dealing with Flask REST API?

Tags: url, python-3.x, flask, werkzeug

I have a flask based web application running, I am not sure whether the following two urls are equivalent with respect to a Flask request

```
www.example.com/hello?a=Hello+G%C3%BCnter
```

and

```
www.example.com/hello?a=Hello Günter
```

How are these urls translated into a Flask Request internally ?  Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser (or any other http client, like curl) should translate both of these urls into `www.example.com/hello?a=Hello+G%C3%BCnter` before sending to server, because `www.example.com/hello?a=Hello Günter` is not a valid HTTP URL. So Flask will receive `www.example.com/hello?a=Hello+G%C3%BCnter` in both cases, and supply it to view function arguments decoded, as `"Hello Günter"`.